# Should the admin and administrator tags on the main site be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

I can't really think why this would not be a good idea:

- [admin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/admin) 28 uses (9 this year)
- [administrator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administrator) 14 uses (5 this year)

Comment: On first inspection, it looks like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, let's first flush out what these tags mean to the site by having someone write a wiki summary for both tags (or at least propose what the tag *should* mean for the site in an answer here). Unless we have a good reason to keep them, let's just clean up the questions and let the nightly unused tag culling put them both out of their misery.

What sort of questions should be collected under https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administrator and what sort of questions should be collected under https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/admin

It's not clear to me that we even need either of the tags and really we could edit the questions / merge them down to point to [Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) or [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx)

We could merge and then clean up later as it appears both tags suffer from vague use patterns.

Comment: A very quick look suggests some explicitly depen on the admin group or Administrative use so there will be some questions left on the tag

Comment: Also admin is the unix level user but a dialog will say system administrator so I think they will end up being the same